# Finding the Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices then

$$\det\left((A^T)^7B^{-15}A^{29}(B^T)^{11}A^{-36}B^4\right)=1.$$

I'm guessing the expression inside the brackets simplifies to the identity matrix, but I'm having trouble simplifying this expression at all. How do you do this?

Comment: Not even $C=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ simplifies to the identity matrix (usually), but we do have $\det(C)=1$.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve question?

Comment: Determinant is a group homomorphism from invertible matrices $n \times n$ to invertible matrices $1 \times 1$, that is nonzero elements of field; it's also evidently same for matrix and its transpose.

Comment: There is a general property of determinants you can use. What properties do you know?

Comment: Intuitively, determinant is a measure of the hypervolume scale factor of a linear map; multiplication of matrices is composition of linear maps; scaling volume first by $a$ and then by $b$ is the same as scaling by the product $ab$.

Comment: I've tried using all the properties of inverses and transposes that i can think of. But i still can't seem to simplify the expression to anything of use.

Comment: Stuart, the solution is trivial. You need to look up "determinant" again and then read alll comments again. Another hint: the exponents $7+29-36=0$ for $A$, and $-15+11+4=0$ for $B$.

Comment: The important part that you need is that $\det{XY} = \det{X}\det{Y}$. From this you follow that $\det{X^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\det{X}}$ if such an inverse exists, and I hope you know that $\det{X^T} = \det{X}$. From this you can simplify the whole expression as products of powers of $\det{A}$ and $\det{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \det((A^T)^7 \times B^{-15}  \times A^{29} \times (B^T)^{11} \times A^{-36} \times B^4) \\
&= \det((A^T)^7) \det(B^{-15}) \det(A^{29}) \det((B^T)^{11}) \det((A)^{-36}) \det(B^4) \tag{$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$}\\
&= \det(A^T)^7 \det(B)^{-15} \det(A)^{29} \det(B^T)^{11} \det(A)^{-36} \det(B)^4 \\
&= \det(A)^7 \det(B)^{-15} \det(A)^{29} \det(B)^{11} \det(A)^{-36} \det(B)^4 \tag{$\det(A^T) = \det(A)$}\\
&= \det(A)^{7+29-36} \det(B)^{-15+11+4} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Comment: I think, the OP should have tried this himself:)

Comment: Why does det(A)^0 det(B)^0 = 1?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree.  I should have asked OP to post his work when he says that he "can't seem to simplify the expression to anything of use" after "using all the properties of inverses and transposes".

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney $\det(A), \det(B)$ are numbers, and $a^0 = 1$ for all $a \ne 0$.